# Arrow button with vertical gradient background

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I need to make this button:

[image: Button]

Usually when I need to make arrow button with gradient and border, I add `.button:before` element with absolute positioning, using `transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(%SOMETHING%);` and adding `background: linear-gradient(45deg, %COLORS%);`. But now I need to make button, arrow angle of which is not right. How can I do it?

Comment: why cant you use **:before** for button also. it will work, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can design this button using `:before` selector:

```css
.button {
   width: 120px;
   height: 50px;   
   position: relative;
   -moz-border-radius:    5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius:         5px;
   border:1px solid #4d7a9c; 
   position:relative;
   color:white;
   font-size:18px;
   
   background: #238fe7; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #238fe7 0%, #156fba 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #238fe7 0%,#156fba 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #238fe7 0%,#156fba 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#238fe7', endColorstr='#156fba',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ 
 }

.button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleX(0.6) rotate(45deg);
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  right:-18px;
  top:5px;
  border-radius:  5px;
  z-index:-1px;
  
  background: #238fe7; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #238fe7 0%, #156fba 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #238fe7 0%,#156fba 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #238fe7 0%,#156fba 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#238fe7', endColorstr='#156fba',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Text</button>
```

Comment: I'm impressed.  For a button like this I won't even try a pure CSS solution. I'll go SVG directly because I wouldn't imagine a CSS solution would even achieve concordance on corner radii as you achieved here. Congrats!

Comment: Awesome! It is working very good, I think it is also good to add `outline: none;` to it.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this :

```css
#trape {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  border:0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, tan);
}

#trape:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: scaleX(0.6) rotate(45deg);
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  right:-18px;
  top:7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, red, tan);
}
```

```html
<button id="trape"></button>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You can also add `scaleX(0.6)` to the transform property to adapt the angle of the arrow

Comment: @Thinker, yes, I've written that I usually use it, but the angle is right.

Comment: @FelixYadomi the problem will be in gradient, gradient wont be the same as `button`'s gradient

Comment: @FelixYadomi Couldn't help adding your idea to the snippet :-)